# Ιnitial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

*Let the initial value problem :*

$$y' = x\ln y, y(1)=1$$

*Study the existence of solutions in a domain around the initial value and study its uniqueness too*.

I know that an initial value problem has a unique solution if the function completes the *Lipshitz Condition*, but I am not sure on how to show it. I do not know how to proceed on the first part, studying the existence of the solutions.

We've only approached theorems and their proofs so I have completely no experience over exercises, I would really appreciate a thorough solution or explanation on how to handle such problems, because I really have an issue regarding exercises since we haven't been given books/leaflets yet.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: write $$\frac{dy}{\ln(y)}=xdx$$

Comment: How will I show that it's Lipschitz though ? I know the ODE gets solved by that way.

Comment: Lipschitz with respect to $x$ or $y$?

Comment: Shouldn't it be with respect to $y$ since we want to see if the solution is unique ? Or what should I do ? I'm just trying to figure out how I should be handling this, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: we have $$x(\ln(y_2)-\ln(y_1))=x\frac{1}{\xi}(y_2-y_1)$$ with $\xi$ between $$y_2,y_1$$

Comment: So, it's again using the standard trick of the *Mean Value Theorem*. Thanks a lot for the answers !

Comment: By the way, the integral $\int \frac{1}{\ln y} dy$ cannot be evaluated, so how would I proceed on the solution part ?

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos It can be evaluated with the [logarithmic integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html).